# typescript fn return map object of composed functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

i'm trying to type a helper function that takes in an object of functions and wrap it in another fn;

```js
const bindFn = (obj, wrapFn) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((carry, [key, fn])=>{
carry[key] = ( ...args ) => wrapFn(fn.apply(null, args))
return carry;
},{})


// example of usage

const n = bindFn( { sum: (x) => x+1 }, console.log);
n.sum(3); // this should console.log 4
```

problem is i have no clue how to type bindFn to return proper type that contains an object with same keys and return types of supplied object. something like

```
interface BindFn = {
[name: keysof obj] : () => Returntype<obj[name]> :D !!! no clue.
}
```

Comment: it just returns the type of obj? because wrapFn is executed the output will be the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const bindFn = <T extends {[key: string]: Function}>(
  obj: T,
  wrapFn: Function
) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((carry, [key, fn]) => {
    carry[key] = (...args) => wrapFn(fn.apply(null, args));
    return carry;
  }, {}) as T;
};

const n = bindFn({ sum: (x: number) => x + 1 }, console.log);
n.sum(3);
n.sum('3'); // error: type string does not match number
n.foo(2);   // error: 'foo' does not exist on the first arg of bindFn
const z = bindFn('foo', console.log); // error: 'foo' is not the right shape
```

This way, you get useful type checking because the return type of `bindFn()` will always be the same shape as its first parameter. e.g., `n.sum()` will be of type `(x: number) => x + 1` because that's what was passed to `bindFn()` (because `return ... as T`)

[image: VSCode hinting]

It will also enforce that the shape of the first parameter of `bindFn()` must be an object with keys that are functions (because `T extends {[key: string]: Function}`)

[image: More VSCode hinting]

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you want? think this is right.

```
const bindFn = <A extends keyof any, B>(obj: Record<A, B>, wrapFn: (fn: (arg: B) => B) => any): typeof obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((carry, [key, fn])=>{
    carry[key] = ( ...args: any[] ) => wrapFn(fn.apply(null, args))
    return carry;
}, {})

const obj = { name: () => "my name is", age: () => "my age is" };
const result = bindFn(obj, (arg) => {
    console.log("executed on");
    return arg;
})
```

or the executed the function, version

```
const bindFn = <A extends keyof any, B , C>(obj: Record<A, B>, wrapFn: (fn: (arg: B) => any) => C): Record<A, C> => Object.entries(obj).reduce((carry, [key, fn])=>{
    carry[key] = ( ...args: any[] ) => wrapFn(fn.apply(null, args))
    return carry;
}, {})

const obj = { name: () => "my name is", age: () => "my age is" };
const result = bindFn(obj, (arg) => {
    console.log("executed on");
    return 5;
}) // {name: number, age: number}
```